# install OpenCL ICD Loader to ubuntu12 on Zedboard occured error

Tags: opencl, embedded-linux, zynq, pocl

i want to run opencl on zedboard and now i'm failing to install ocl_icd on ubuntu12

i refer to the page "https://github.com/umaurmi/OPENCL_EXAMPLES_ZEDBOARD/wiki/Installing-POCL-dependencies-on-Ubuntu-linux-based-targets"

"./configure" complete without errors 
but "make" cause errors ,show below

```
root@localhost:~/Downloads/ocl-icd-1.2.1# make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/ocl-icd-1.2.1'
  CC     libOpenCL_la-ocl_icd_loader.lo
  CC     libOpenCL_la-ocl_icd_loader_gen.lo
In file included from ocl_icd_loader_gen.c:30:0:
ocl_icd_debug.h: In function 'debug_init':
ocl_icd_debug.h:66:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'getenv'     [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
ocl_icd_debug.h:66:17: error: initialization makes pointer from integer     without a cast [-Werror]
ocl_icd_debug.h:68:7: error: implicit declaration of function 'atoi'         [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [libOpenCL_la-ocl_icd_loader_gen.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/ocl-icd-1.2.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

how can i do for that?